# Duplicate the content of a SQL Server database for a load test

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, load-testing

I have the following problem. I have a SQL Server database with a total size of 3 GB. The contents of this database are used for the analysis in a data cube. I want to test the performance of this data cube by a database size of 30 GB. What is the best way to do this? Duplicate multiple times the content of the database? In this case the foreign keys would be a real problem, cause I want to keep the relationships between the tuples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I once tried that, but gave up. Like you said, FKs were a real pain in the butt. Something like SQL Data Generator may help you: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/

Comment: @ZoffDino Thank you for the advice. I gonna try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tricky way to do it. Here is a sketch of my approach:

1. Turn off the identities in the tables whose content has to be duplicated
2. Turn off the constraint check for all tables
3. Make a copy of the DB and work with the copy from now on
4. Increase all ID's in relevant tables by a high value, for example by 10.000.000
5. Merge the manipulated DB copy with the original DB
6. Make a copy of the merged DB and perform step 4 again with increment by another smaller value (for example by 5.000.000) and merge it with original DB again
7. Perform the steps 3 to 5 until the wished DB size is reached
8. After you finish don't forget to turn on the identities and constraint checks for all effected tables

Using the described approach I was able to increase the number of movies in my DB from 5 to 60 in four iterations and successfully perform the necessary load test.

Be careful by choosing the values for the increment! First I used 10.000.000, than 5.000.000, than 2.000.000 and finally 1.000.000 to avoid ID intersections.